# Is there any way to use hms image kit on api level 21?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

> What are the requirements of Image Kit on mobile devices and software?
> In principle, Huawei devices running Android 8.0 or later supports
> Image Kit if HMS Core (APK) 4.0.2.300 or later has been installed. If
> the fallback-SDK is used, this requirement can be ignored.

This is what huawei's site claims so it requires api 26, but does the fallback-SDK work on api 21 or the fallback means it works on devices without HMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fallback SDK means it can works on devices without HMS (it means HMS Core APK 4.0.2.300 here).

Normally fallback SDK used for devices which are not produced by Huawei.

However fallback SDK requires same software and minSDK as HMS, it also needs Android 8.0 or later and api 26.